# Java: Installing new fonts for Windows

Tags: java, windows, fonts

I got a problem here, we have an application which require specific fonts to be installed in Windows and in some cases customers are missing them.

So it was decided to bundle them together with application and install if they are missing.
So far im testing runnable jar where I include all required fonts (*.ttf) as resources and trying to install them from code

for example here i'm checking if required font is missing:

```
GraphicsEnvironment gr = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] allSystemFonts = gr.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
if (!Arrays.asList(allSystemFonts).contains("YourMissingFontName"))
{
    System.out.println("Fonts are missing, installing...");
    installMissingFonts(getLocalFonts());
}
```

in function "getLocalFonts" im getting fonts from embedded jar resources as array of files

```
File localFontFolder = new File(
     this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Fonts/")
    .getFile());
return localFontFolder.listFiles();
```

And registering them in the System with "registerFont" in "installMissingFonts" function

```
for (File file : allFonts) {
    try{
        Font fontFile = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
        gr.registerFont(fontFile);
        System.out.println("Font [" + fontFile.getFontName() +"] was registred successfully");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed register font from ["+file+"]: "+e);
    }
}
```

That works perfectly within a run time, and if i'll call check over again after registration was complete, it will not say to me that fonts are missing what is exactly what I need

However it is not installing them into C:\Windows\Fonts folder and those registered fonts are discarded after lunch time. So each time I would run the jar it will install those fonts but only for a duration of application live within its own virtual space.
Running it as Admin on Win7 doesn't help, it still working only for a duration of application live

Question:
How do I install missing fonts to the System (C:\Windows\Fonts) from Java code if I have required fonts as *.ttf files embedded as resource?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rely on Java code to do this, it's better if you just bundle a Windows Installer (MSI) with your app.

You can use the  [WIX tool set](http://wixtoolset.org/) to do this.  Use WIX to create an minimal UI-less installer (MSI file) that just installs the fonts with the [RegisterFonts](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registerfonts.html) directive.  Or a full installer that installs the app as well.

If your Java application has any sort of installer script, you can have it invoke your MSI file (Runtime.exec). Otherwise, bundle the MSI as a resource like you are bundling the fonts. On the the first time your app runs or when it detects the fonts are missing, have it exec the MSI file.

Ideally, you have WIX build a full installer that installs both the Fonts and Java code together and you distribute the MSI (or setup.exe) for them to launch.