# how to install fonts in maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, fonts, installation

i wanted to install FONTS for writing PDF in other language .
currently fonts are installed  i n operating system e.g windows 
can we configure fonts directly in project without using OS fonts.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565119/java-installing-new-fonts-for-windows

Comment: Another question in pure java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java/5652385#5652385

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a custom font in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java)